# Store/Restore snapshot/state of entire application

Tags: java, state, store, restore

I want to store the entire application state and then restore it on the next start. Is there a library which would make it easier for me? Or does anyone of you have any suggestions?

Standalone Application

Comment: what kind of application? Web or Standalone?

Comment: standalone application

Comment: I would serialize all the objects that reside in my application at runtime

Comment: @JavaHopper: that implies that every object is serializable

Comment: Create your state via objects with annotations and you can use [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) which works much like XMLSerializer in C#.

Comment: @JavaHopper That's a big no-no. Serialization should only be used under special circumstances, and serialized objects should *never* be stored on your disk (or used anywhere outside of the software for a timeframe that exceeds the running time of your software). Otherwise you'll be leaking implementation, potentially resulting in not being able to unmarshall data that exists outside of the application if you were to modify the code to fix a bug (or even just to clean it up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a design pattern that is used for your purpouse, and it is the Memento Pattern.

> The memento pattern is implemented with three objects: the originator, a caretaker and a memento. The originator is some object that has an internal state. The caretaker is going to do something to the originator, but wants to be able to undo the change. The caretaker first asks the originator for a memento object. Then it does whatever operation (or sequence of operations) it was going to do. To roll back to the state before the operations, it returns the memento object to the originator. The memento object itself is an opaque object (one which the caretaker cannot, or should not, change). - Wikipedia

You can read the example provided in the wiki page to understand how to use it inside your code.

If you want to save the state of an object as a file, and have it avaiable even after the execution of your program is over, you should implement the Serializable interface in the class you want to store.

Example:

```
public class Example implements Serializable
    {

    }
```

and where you instantiate that class:

```
try{

    Example c = new Example();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("YOURPATH");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);   
    oos.writeObject(c);
    oos.close();
    System.out.println("Done");

   }catch(Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: @Eric You may want to avoid this strategy. Imagine this: Someone is using your application. An `Example` object is stored to their drive on exit. One day, you find a bug/mistake in `Example` (maybe you mispelled a word), so you edit `Example` to fix the bug. When people open the application back up, it'll try to load in the `Example` object from the drive, **but will fail**, since fixing the bug actually changes the binary representation of `Example`. Serializing objects "leaks implementation", preventing you from modifing the class if instances already exist outside of the app (on your drive)