# which of the following is the best way of creating a file?

Tags: java, database, data-structures

What is the difference between them?

How can I store data in a text format and retrieve it when I want?

how can I store data in a simple way until I learn sql?

```
 try{

     FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\acer\\Downloads\\java     Q//somthing.txt");
     fileWriter.write("here is the first text");

     fileWriter.append(" \n the secound one ");
     fileWriter.close();

 } // try

 catch(IOException e){

     System.out.println(" an error occer ");


} // catch
```

or that way

```
WriteFile writeFile=new WriteFile(); // a class WriteFile the implements   Serilizable


 try{

 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\acer\\Downloads\\java Q//something.ser");

 ObjectOutputStream objectoutputs=new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

 objectoutputs.writeObject(writeFile);

 objectoutputs.flush();

 objectoutputs.close();
 } // try

 catch(IOException e){

     System.out.println("an error occer");

} // catch
```

Comment: It depends on the requirements of your software. Serialization can be dangerous, check out [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904182/store-restore-snapshot-state-of-entire-application/38904365#comment65227627_38904365) I wrote on why you may want to avoid serialization when it comes to storing state onto your drive. I'd recommend a simple `FileWriter` or storing state to a `Properties` file. If the users shouldn't read the data when stored to the drive, you could create your own encryption system to convert the state being being stored.

Comment: In 2016, "pure java object serialiazation" would definitely not be your first choice. It comes with a lot of restrictions; even security risks. If at all, consider to "serialize" into JSON strings and save those as human readable text. That makes testing much easier for you; and given your naive ideas; I guess you will be spending a lot of time ... testing and debugging.

Comment: @GhostCat JSON is easy to read. If being stored to a drive, users could (easily) access and edit the JSON to exploit the software. There are other forms of local persistent storage that are easy to test yet hard to exploit. It strongly depends on the requirements of his software.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Not sure if I agree with that. Any application that is reading in data should use certain precaution. If data is written to file, the format really doesn't matter.

Comment: @GhostCat The format *does* matter. Lets say you store the amount of cash the user has in JSON form. There's no way to double check whether the value being read is the same value that was written. They could easily give themselves unlimited cash. The idea is to make this harder for the user (that's really all security is: increased complexity). In theory, anything client-side could be exploited. The goal is to make it harder to exploit (or keep it on the server). If this was an offline game, the user could easily exploit the software if stored as JSON (I do it all the time with android apps).

Comment: @GhostCat As for an "all-in-one best-persistent-storage", it doesn't exist. It'll either be overpowered or underpowered, oversecure or not secure enough. I'd be able to give an answer if I was given more context about his software requirements. And keep in mind, it shouldn't be easy to read to the user unless it's intended that they edit the file. It should only be easy to read into the system, which can be made easy by stacking different APIs to achieve different forms of security (assuming those APIs are easy to use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can write it as text, use that. It's the simplest to work with.  You can view it and edit it in a text editor.

You should use serialization when you have objects which can't be easy turned into text (or for performance reasons, although Java Serialization is very slow so it's not a good choice for that either)

BTW: I would avoid

- using both `\\` and `/` in the path. Just use one or the other.
- using multiple spaces in a directory name. This is confusing IMHO, unless you can say why you are using exactly that meany spaces.
- Use `.write()` or `.append()` but not both.
- Use try-with-resource to close off the Closeable FileWriter.

e.g.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\acer\\Downloads\\java Q\\something.txt");
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file)) {
   ps.println("here is the first text");
   ps.println("the second one ");
}
```